# SAP HANA spatial function

Tags: hana, spatial-query

I want to create function in SAP HANA DB for calculation distance between two points.

```
create function "kostya"."calc_distance" (in a ST_Point, in b ST_Point)
returns dist DOUBLE
AS
BEGIN
    dist = a.ST_Distance(b);
END
```

when I have tried to execute this code I have got error:

> feature not supported: Unsupported parameter type:ST_POINT: line 2 col 48 (at pos 48)

but when I have executed similar SQL query:

```
select NEW ST_Point(10, 1).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point(1, 1)) FROM dummy;
```

I have got write result.

Any tips ?

Comment: I use eclipse with sap hana plugins.

Comment: I used this example for my function https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOB83B1vulk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d467407519101484f190f545d54b24/content.htm) we learn:

> The input and output parameters of a procedure can have any of the primitive SQL types or a table type.

Geospatial data types are, unfortunately, not listed as such.

So you will have to pass scalare values like `a.ST_X()` to the function and combine them back to an `ST_Point` within the procedure using the [`ST_Point(DOUBLE, DOUBLE)` constructor](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/7a/287dcd787c1014937db68d54b4e08c/content.htm?frameset=/en/7a/27aec5787c10148627d902a0417f25/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/99/d10e4fdaaf41588480a43478e840d5/plain.htm&node_id=140) like so:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "calc_distance" (
    IN a_long DOUBLE, 
    IN a_lat DOUBLE, 
    IN b_long DOUBLE, 
    IN b_lat DOUBLE
) RETURNS dist DOUBLE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW ST_Point(:a_long, :a_lat).ST_Distance(
        NEW ST_Point(:b_long, :b_lat)) INTO dist FROM dummy;
END;

-- sample usage
SELECT "calc_distance"(a.ST_X(), a.ST_Y(), b.ST_X(), b.ST_Y())
FROM (
    SELECT NEW ST_Point(10.0, 50.0) AS a, NEW ST_Point(11.0, 51.0) AS b FROM dummy
);
```

This works without complaint from the Web Based Development Workbench of HANA 102.01. From a Eclipse Luna with SAP Development Tools for Eclipse installed, we get

```
java.sql.SQLWarning: Not recommended feature: Using SELECT INTO in Scalar UDF
Statement 'CREATE FUNCTION "calc_distance" ( IN a_long DOUBLE, IN a_lat DOUBLE, IN b_long DOUBLE, IN b_lat ...' 
successfully executed in 16 ms 272 µs  (server processing time: 7 ms 460 µs) - Rows Affected: 0
```

Maybe in SAP HANA Studio the warning becomes an error. Seems that things are in process over there :)

As of SAP HANA SPS11, there is extended support for spatial datatypes. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOB83B1vulk) from the SAP HANA Academy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried your example but it does not work for me. SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: Scalar UDF does not support SQL statements

Comment: What HANA SP? Mine was a SP10.

Comment: Sorry I am beginner in SAP. I have used SAP HANA CLOUD with trial account.  Database version 1.00.102.03.1449674847

Comment: Almost current cloud version. Mine is not newer. Code above should work. Pls give precise error you are experiencing.

Comment: works in the Web Based Development Workbench. I will try in HANA Studio tomorrow morning and come back to you.

Comment: Yes it works in web ide. And why it does not work with ST_Geometry types with in parameters like in video ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOB83B1vulk

Comment: Notes read: "Please note that this feature is applicable to SPS11 of HANA and will not work in previous versions." Thanks for pointing me to the video :)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107037/discussion-between-konstantyn-and-flaschbier).